# Show that $| u_2 + v_2 -1 | - |u_1 + v_2 -1| - |u_2 + v_1 -1| + |u_1 + v_1 - 1| \geq 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Quick question, assume $u_1 \leq u_2$, $v_1 \leq v_2$ $\in [0,1]$. I'm trying to show that

$$ | u_2 + v_2 -1 | - |u_1 + v_2 -1| - |u_2 + v_1 -1| + |u_1 + v_1 - 1| \geq 0$$

**My idea is that** the following holds:

$$ \begin{array}{rl} &| u_2 + v_2 -1 | - |u_2 + v_1 -1| - |u_1 + v_2 -1| + |u_1 + v_1- 1| \geq \\ &\geq | u_2 + v_2 - 1 - [u_2 + v_1 - 1]| + |u_1 + v_1 - 1 - [u_1 + v_2 - 1]| \\
&\geq |v_2 - v_1| + |v_1 - v_2| \\
&\geq 0 \end{array}$$

But I'm not sure about the first $\geq$. The idea is to inverse something like the known $|x - y| \leq |x|+|y|$, but not sure about the negative signs here.

**Edit:**
OR:
$$ \begin{array}{rl} &| u_2 + v_2 -1 | - |u_2 + v_1 -1| - |u_1 + v_2 -1| + |u_1 + v_1- 1| = \\
&| u_2 + v_2 -1 | + |u_1 + v_1- 1| - (|u_2 + v_1 -1| + |u_1 + v_2 -1|)  \geq \\
 &\geq | u_2 + v_2 - 1 - [u_1 + v_1 - 1]| - (|u_2 + v_1 -1| + |u_1 + v_2 -1|) \\
 &= [u_2 - u_1] + [v_2-v_1]  - (|u_2 + v_1 -1| + |u_1 + v_2 -1|) \\
 &= ([u_2 - v_1] - |u_2 + v_1 -1|) + ([v_2-u_1]  - |v_2 + u_1 +  -1|) \\
&= \max(1-u_2, v_1) + \max(1-v_2, u_1) \\
&\geq 0 \end{array}$$